# Performance impact in using camelCase in Cassandra columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I know, Cassandra generally converts all the column names into lowercase.

Is there a performance impact in using the camelCase in column names in Cassandra?

I used the double quote in columns and I am able to store the column names in the camelCase, like below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  Foo int PRIMARY KEY,
  "Bar" int
);
```

Will there be a performance impact in storing the column name with the double quotes?

Comment: I don't think there is any impact. Please explain if you have any particular use case to follow such style. Based on my experience, it's better to stick with recommended guideline, so that it's easier to read, maintain, and avoid unnecessary escaping or extra character (e.g. double quote, /, etc.)

Comment: If I keep all the column names (say one column name as 'username') in small case, then I need to copy all the columns back to another format (say userName) to send back to API response

Comment: understand your point. I think you have found lost of inputs in below answers. I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an impact. I would say that the case-insensitive nature of CQL only serves the purpose of simplifying queries, as you can see from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28447941/824644

Also, it seems that there was a motivation for this behavior due to the preference of lower camel case in Java (which is the language in which Cassandra is written in). See the discussion in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/reuzel/CqlSharp/issues/28

Comment: How it simplifies the queries?

Comment: If you have everything in lowercase, then you don't need to escape the quotes to run the query (in case you have columns NOT in lowercase). See the SO answer that I have linked.

Comment: Is there a reason why Cassandra converts the columns to lower case?

Comment: In short: No. :)

Comment: But this is surprising, why Cassandra converts everything to lower case without any reason :(

Comment: It's a good question. I was curious so I investigated the JIRA issues of the Cassandra project, but I didn't find anything relevant. I would say that the reasons for the transformation to lowercase are lost in some private chat among the developers that first implemented this. This is everything that I found: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7093?jql=project%20%3D%20CASSANDRA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Columns%20lowercase%22

Comment: Actually, see the last comment on this issue (another proof that this behavior is really just for historical reasons): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5879

Answer (score 2):

Space wise no. Performance wise, no. (Well, even assuming you have to wire the double quotes, if you use prepared statements, you will send once, so it is negligible)

On Cassandra 3, the names are only written once on the Header of the sstables (Reference: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/03/04/introductiont-to-the-apache-cassandra-3-storage-engine.html).

It gets pretty weird on having to always provide the double quotes (CQLSH for example), so I normally don't do it.
Also, older cluster that started with Thrift and migrated to CQL have a lot of that. So, to avoid confusion regarding the origins (but there are better ways of verifying this) it is good to keep the quotes away.

Comment: Say It is a new application which uses Cassandra 3.0, So It is fine to use the double quotes? + Why Cassandra internally converts to lower case as default?

Answer (score 1):

There's no impact performance wise. CQL downcases unquoted identifiers.
I understand it may cause trouble for developers, as it may be easy to handle camel or mixed cases but if you're trying to access the table through APIs then you may have defined a class that maps to that table. I don't see any overhead where you would need to change the table name and etc when accessing through the API.

Moreover, when you've a bigger team of developers it is seen as a good data modeling practice to name columns as lowercase or use underscores instead of camel case. That is done as default by cassandra. If you really need the casing then just use double quotes.